# What is and how to increase the maximum number of usb devices?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, kernel, usb-storage, hub

I'm wondering what is the maximum number of USB devices the Linux kernel can manage?
Does this depend on the root-Hub or something else, too?

**Is there a way to increase this maximum number?**

I need to do this, because I've ran into problems while trying to write to a large amount of USB sticks. To do this, I have a setup as follows:

There is 1 computer running Ubuntu Linux, with 3 (active) HUBs attached to 3 USB ports of this machine.
All of those three HUBs are 7 port HUBs. To 6 of those 7 ports, more HUBs are attached.
This gives me the number of 3 * 6 = 18 HUBs in the "second" layer.
Each of these HUBs is an active 7 port HUB, too.
There is a USB stick attached to every port of those second layer HUBs.
In total I have 126 USB Sticks connected to the computer.

I have a script that searches for all USB disk devices (through listing /dev/disk/by-path/ ). Each of the USB disk devices is then first partitioned, written to using cp and then made bootable using syslinux. This is NOT done in parallel!

**The problem:**
I only get 105 USB disk devices using

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-path | grep usb | grep -v part | wc -l
```

The LEDs of the sticks in 3 rows (one row corresponds to one HUB in the second layer) are off, too.

How do I get all of those sticks to work? (Or possibly even more?)

Comment: Are the hubs powered (as in, with their own power adapters, not just through the USB connection)? If not, you're probably just running out of power over your USB connection.

Comment: Yes, all of the HUBs are powered.

Comment: Have you moved the hub which is not powering the sticks? It may be defective. Try it directly in a port on the box.

Comment: Does the missing number of devices in /dev/disk correspond exactly to the unlit sticks?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, the number of missing sticks (21) does exactly correspond to the number of unlit sticks.

Comment: @CharlieRB: The whole setup is working with WinXP. At least, that's what I've been told. But I will test that. But I think it is very unlikely that one or more of the HUBs is defect, because everytime I disconnect and then reconnect the whole setup, three different HUBs are not powering their sticks.

Comment: What do you see in dmesg when you unplug and replug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's by standard as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_device#System_design

You can't have more than 127 devices (hub inclusive) connected to a single host controller.

Now: the host controller+3 hub (1st layer)+18 hub (2nd layer) = 22 devices that DON'T appear as disk devices.

127 minus these 22 USB devices = 105 devices that can be managed by the kernel as disks.

127 devices is a hard limit of the USB protocol (see here: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb3.shtml#USBProtocols) because the ADDR address field is seven bit long.

So by software there is no way to increase it. 
Maybe you can try with more than a host controller interface, or change topology by reducing the number of hubs (thus increasing the number of disks seen by the system).

Comment: Perhaps you can temporary disable some devices, allowing other to be plugged in, meaning that you can work with 105 disks at a time. But I don't know how to unplug and replug usb devices via software.

Comment: Is that 127 devices globally for the host?  Seems like the controller itself would form part of the addressing, i.e. the card or chip with the usb ports connected.