# What defines maximum numbers of USBs connected?

Tags: usb, usb-3

By default maximum possible USB devices connected is 128. Different motherboards support different numbers. Most of them do not go that high. But how is that number defined? 
I mean for example x86 CPUs can only recognize up to 4GB of RAM due to 32-bit address length only going up to a specific size therefore maximum number of different memory addresses has cap which is 4GB of RAM while 64-bit addresses are much bigger.

Is there a similar explanation for USB devices?
Does that change with USB-3 or does USB-3 only affect speed of connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/371051/what-is-and-how-to-increase-the-maximum-number-of-usb-devices

Comment: See http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb3.shtml#USBProtocols 

**ADDR**

The address field specifies which device the packet is designated for. **Being 7 bits in length allows for 127 devices to be supported.**

Comment: What about USB-3. Does that change the protocol? and the address size?

Comment: It is the same for USB 3.0.

Comment: OK. Thanks then. I suppose this is a complete duplicate of the suggested question

Comment: @Ramhound no. after the comments this is more of a duplicate to
http://superuser.com/questions/371051/what-is-and-how-to-increase-the-maximum-number-of-usb-devices